# Representations of $S_3$

Tags: representation-theory

In [these Karen Smith's notes on representation of finite groups](http://users.jyu.fi/~laurikah/REP/REPtext2010_2.pdf), on page 50 the irreducible representations of $S_3$ are found.

If $\sigma=(1 2 3)$ and $V$ is a complex representation of $S_3$, I don't understand what "the action of $\sigma$ on $V$" means. Is it this:

$\langle\sigma\rangle \times V \to V$

$\sigma \cdot (v_1,\dots,v_n)=(v_{\sigma(1)},v_{\sigma(2)},v_{\sigma(3)},v_4,\dots,v_n)$

where $\langle\sigma\rangle$ means the subgroup of $S_3$ generated by $\sigma$?

Comment: Bruno, she is considering *a* complex representation $V$ which comes with an action of the group elements on $V$.

Comment: Yes, that map $\langle\sigma\rangle \times V \rightarrow V$ is the action. You can find more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Comment: @Mariano: how silly of me, of course, it's just the restriction of the action that comes with the representation :) Thank you. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. @joriki: in consequence, what I said about that map is wrong :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She is considering *a* complex representation *V* which comes with an action of the group elements on *V*.